# Can't read related data LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I retrieve a set of records via LINQ with a chain of Include statements then a Where. Those records are stored in a table, the Solicitud de AccionN table (which I pass to the view), that has another three related tables: Analisis Causal, Plan de Accion & Evaluacion Efectividad.

The Where statement asks for the UserId (ResponsableId) of the user currently logged in. I'm asking for all the Solicitud de Accion records that have the UserId as responsible. Piece of cake because UserId is a field in the table so all I do is ask for it. Above all, the other three tables - Analisis Causal, Plan de Accion & Evaluacion Efectividad - have the same field UserId (ResponsableId).

My current LINQ expression is:

```
var sacSolicitudAccion = 
  db.SacSolicitudAccion.Include(s => s.SacResponsables)
                       .Include(s => s.SacAnalisisCausal)
                       .Include(s => s.SacPlanesAccion)
                       .Include(s => s.SacEvalEfectividad)
                       .Where(s => s.SacResponsablesID == idUsuario);
```

Now the real question. I need to show every Solicitud de Accion that the user currently logged in is responsible for and every Solicitud de Accion where the user is responsible either for the Analisis Causal, Plan de Accion or Evaluacion Efectividad.

How can I do this?

*Important: Solicitud de Accion has this relationship with the other three tables:

- Solicitud de Accion has many Analisis Causal and Analisis Causal has one Solicitud de Accion) and the ResponsableId (UserId) is a field in every table so it is the same Where for all tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i  solved this. But i had to redesign the entire structure to a ViewModel approach. I took the long road and create three collectiones of the same type, SacSolicitudesAccion, but with different names. Something like this (in the VM):

```
public ICollection<SacSolicitudAccion> OverdueRequest { get; set; }
public ICollection<SacSolicitudAccion> OverdueRequestByActionPlan { get; set; }
public ICollection<SacSolicitudAccion> OverdueRequestByEfectiveness { get; set; }
```

I set a AsQueryable variable that holds all records, you may think that it can bring some perfomance issues but don't underestimate the power of LINQ and this framework, the thing is very fast. By doing

Then i read every SacSolicitudAccion, SacPlanesAccion & SacEvaluacion in that variable to check if they are overdue and select the SacSolicitudAccion and bind that to the respective ViewModel statement. Passing the ViewModel to the view required some changes in the view but very trivial, instead of foreach(var item in Model) now it is foreach(var item in Model.Entity). Simple as that.

The tricky part then was managing and rewriting the filters but that's another story.

Thanks to everyone for your answers! Greetings!

Answer (score -1):

```
.Where(s => s.SacResponsablesID == idusuario ||
            s.SacPlanesAccion.SacResponsablesID == idusuario ||
            s.SacEvalEffectividad.SacResponsablesID == iduario);
```

Should be a replacement for your `Where` clause that gets you what you need. Note that you may not need all those includes, since if your application code isn't using it and the above is translated to SQL, you don't need to bring the data points over.

Comment: How do you know that he's not using the included information when processing the results of the query?  He hasn't shown what he's doing with the results of the query.  Also, your `Where` isn't any different than the OP's.  The whole idea of how EF handles relationships is that the referenced collections only contain items who's primary key matches the given item.

Comment: @Servy: I explicitly said "if your application code isn't using it and the above is translated to SQL". Honestly the naming threw me off and I had a hard time tracing primary keys, I assumed there was a non-primary relationship involved in some way.

Comment: In fact the Includes are important, just because i need to show related data in the view. Although this solution looks good when i navigate throught the property (e.g. s.SacPlanesAccion. ) it doesn't show SacResponsablesID, it only shows methods like count, concat, aggregate, etc.

I was thinking if there's a way to declare a statement, and then "add" more rows/records. Is that possible? is there a method for that? Do i need something extra in my model or context class so i can navigate through properties like you suggest?

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: @user2631952: If you can make a separate set of statements that together make what you want, you can either store them all in a list, or use `enumberable1.Concat(enumerable2)` ([Enumerable.Concat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894(v=vs.110).aspx))

Comment: Ok, i've used that approach. Save records in a typed List. But, what do i do with the INCLUDE's. Maybe i can save all records in a list and later, just before sending the query to the view attach the includes in the satement.